# PowerShell - foreach() doesn't change element value

Tags: powershell, foreach, scope, reference

Say you have the array:

```
$arr = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
foreach($number in $arr) { $number ++ }
```

I would expect the output to be:

`$arr = @(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Why is this not true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you think you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i++) {
    $arr[$i]++;
}
```

What you're actually doing is equivalent to this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i++) {
    $number = $arr[$i];
    $number++;
}
```

What you really want to do is this:

```
$arr = $arr | ForEach-Object { $_ + 1; }
```

Comment: Nice. Is there any way to do it using the `foreach()` syntax?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Sure, if you want.  You can do `$arr = foreach ($number in $arr) { $number + 1; }`.

Comment: Is there any way to make `$number` reference `$arr[$i]`? I know in PHP you can do this with `&`

Comment: @KolobCanyon Not easily.  Certainly not and still use the `foreach` statement.  You can get a reference to an object with [the `[ref]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-5.1), but that doesn't always work the way you'd expect.  Being based on the .Net Framework and the managed code model, PowerShell references don't really work like PHP references.

Comment: @KolobCanyon Your questions are increasingly sounding like [the XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Maybe you should post a question with the actual problem you're trying to solve or convert from PHP?

Comment: You can't use my previous questions to judge my new ones. That's against the law

Comment: @KolobCanyon Well, it just sounds like you're trying to solve a problem with the techniques you know from PHP.  That's a good idea, but I don't think it'll work if this is the technique you're trying to adapt.  Instead of trying to adapt those techniques into PowerShell, it might be better to ask how to solve the original problem by posting another question with more details about the specifics of the real problem.